# TouchListView inside Dialog

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

This is my debut question here, but I hope start answering soon.

I'm trying to use CommonsWare's TouchListView inside a dialog (a subclass of PreferenceDialog to be precise).

I got the list rendering the items, but they can't be dragged.

Seeing that the component can't be used in other scenarios (like with Fragment or TabGroup) I'm wondering if it's possible to use it in a dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea. It was derived from code that was based on a full-screen `ListView` in an activity. Given the way dialogs work and given how `TouchListView` works, I can see where you might encounter problems. You might consider trying a dialog-themed activity rather than an actual dialog. And, as is noted on the project home page, `TouchListView` is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe I'll consider other desing, 'cause I feel making a new activity doesn't justify the overhead for a simple preference. I saw the project was flagged as unsupported recently.  Have you know an alternative I can use instead?

Comment: I have seen one or two but never really kept track of them, sorry.